# solr shingleFilterFactory not working

Tags: solr, solr6, shingles

Recently I migrated from solr 4 to 6.

In solr 4 `shinglefilterfactory`  is working correctly my configration  is

```
    <fieldType name="text_shingle" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"
                 outputUnigrams="false" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"
                 outputUnigrams="false" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.PositionFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
      </fieldType>
```

But after updating to solr 6 shingles is not working ,schema is as below,

```
        <fieldType name="text_shingle" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
         <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"
                 outputUnigrams="false" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
         <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" minShingleSize="2" maxShingleSize="5"
                 outputUnigrams="false" outputUnigramsIfNoShingles="false" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
      </fieldType>
```

Although in the Analysis tab is was showing proper shingle result but when using in the queryParser it was not giving proper results

My sample hit is

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/shingel_test/select?q=one%20plus%20one&wt=xml&debugQuery=true&defType=edismax&qf=cust_shingle
```

It creates the parsed query as:

```
<str name="rawquerystring">one plus one</str>
<str name="querystring">one plus one</str>
<str name="parsedquery">(+())/no_coord</str>
<str name="parsedquery_toString">+()</str>
<lst name="explain"/>
<str name="QParser">ExtendedDismaxQParser</str>
```